# HAproxy redirection by path doesn't work properly

Tags: redirect, proxy, haproxy

I have a problem setting up a docker container with haproxy.

The infrastructure consists of 3 containers:

- **Main App container** - the main web application
- **Express** - container is an additional web application that has the endpoints "/" and "/about".
- A **haproxy** container that proxies requests to the Express container if a request arrives on the server via the /portal/app path. In other cases, it proxies to Main App container

When opening a page in the browser at the url /portal/app/, there are 2 buttons on the page:

- about `<a href="/about">About</a>`
- news `<a href="/">News</a>`

*If I click on "about", then I get to server.com/about .
If I click on "News", then I get to server.com/*

At the same time, I kind of stay in the session with the Express - container, requests go to the Express - container and not to the Main App container.

If I reload the browser page, then, of course, I get to the Main App container.

[Applying the architecture of the project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3wZl.png)

Applying haproxy config:

```
frontend myfrontend
  bind :80
  bind :443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/haproxy.pem
  http-request redirect scheme https unless { ssl_fc }  
  default_backend main_container


  acl express_app_path path_beg /portal/app 
  use_backend express_app if express_app_path

backend express_app
  log stdout format raw local0
  http-request replace-path /portal/app(/)?(.*) /\2
  server s2 express:3000 check 

backend main_container
  log stdout format raw local0
  server s1 main:3000 check
```

**I want to configure haproxy so that:**

- If I click on "about", then I get to `server.com/portal/app/about`
- If I click on "News", then I get to `server.com/portal/app/` (default page)
- If I refresh the page, I don't get redirected to main container

Answer (score 0):

It's mean you want all request have the path begin by `/portal/app` is go to express app.

And the rest is main app.

Cause the request come to HAPROXY is `domain/portal/app` but when hit the express app which is `localhost/about` and `localhost/`

So, it's need to remove the `portal/app` in path before hit the express app. You can try to use `set-path`

You can check the haproxy document [here](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/haproxy-configuration-tutorials/http-rewrites/#set-the-url-path)

Sample

```
backend express_app
  log stdout format raw local0
  http-request set-path "%[path,regsub(portal/app,)"
  server s2 express:3000 check
```

Comment: ["First answers" feedback:] This answer contains valuable information such as hints, a code sample and a link to the documentation. However, the description of the problem is not yet well understandable and should be made clearer. Also the grammar can be improved, e.g. "It means" instead of "It's mean" and "it's needed" instead of "it's need".